# Is there any way to pluralize some text using knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Text data-bind expressions can have only a single property. How would I pluralize some text depending on the count of another property?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. I demonstrated 2 ways in the fiddles shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/njj2P/2/

The first option I showed is to use a ko.computed to determine if the name should be returned in singular or plural form, based on an evaluation.

```
  this.formattedName = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.qty() > 1 ? this.name() + "s" : this.name();
    }, this);
```

The second option shows how to do this without a computed property, and instead by using a conditional binding.

```
<span data-bind="if:qty()>1">s</span>
```

Comment: I'm really looking for a clean way to do the "y" to "ies" or "x" to "ces," etc. This part is kind of the easy part. I upvoted anyway, but it's not quite what I want. Any ideas? Anything out there?

Comment: I upvoted this answer as I used the second option in it, with slight change to != instead of > so that a value of zero shows the s (ie O sub-items, 1 sub-item, 2 sub-items)

Comment: I agree and made the same observation and change to my code.

Answer (score 13):

You can create a reusable custom binding like the following.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.pluralize = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    function count(data) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data);
        if (typeof value === "object" && value.length > 0) {
            return value.length;
        } else if (typeof value === "number") {
            return value;
        }
    }

    var settings = valueAccessor();
    var text = count(settings.data) === 1 ? settings.singular : settings.plural;
    $(element).text(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(text));
  }
};
```

You would use it like this.

```
<span data-bind="pluralize: { data:items, singular:'entry', plural:'entries' }"></span>
```

- The `data` option can point to any array or number.
- The `singular` option represents the text you want to display if `data` evaluates to 1
- The `plural` option represents the text that will be displayed otherwise.

See it in action here.
http://fiddle.jshell.net/jessegavin/wamfw/

Comment: I quite like this solution actually.

Comment: Great answer!  I recommend adding in a 'none' option and a back-reference to the `count` so that a developer could get options such as `'none' => "No items", 'singular' => "1 item", 'plural' => "## items"`

Comment: Good idea. That's what Angular does.